# Set SelectedValue of DropDownList inside DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagrid, .net-3.5

I got a datagrid where a datasource #1 is bound to, e.g.

```
public class Class
{
  public string Val { get; set; }
  public string Val2 { get; set; }
}
List<Class> classes = new List<Class>();
dgr.DataSource = classes;
```

Inside this datagrid i got a listbox for each row with a datasource #2 bound to:

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Spaltenname">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ListBox runat="server" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" DataSource="<%#oParentTablesHandler.DataTableXYZ%>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

This works, but I have problems setting the SelectedValue.

```
SelectedValue="<%# "" %>
```

will work but I need a selection depending on Val from datasource #1. How can I do that? I need to use Eval i guess, but

```
SelectedValue="<%# Eval("Val") %> did not work...
```

edit: I found out that I want to select an item by text and not by value, argh. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Worse comes to worse, you can always fall back to setting the value on RowDataBound.  Also, by DataGrid, do you mean the 1.1 datagrid, or the 2.0 GridView control?

Comment: It's the 1.1 datagrid, but this shouldn't change anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this..

```
<%# ((Class)Container.DataItem).Val %>
```

UPDATE:

well.there may be some value in 'Val' property that may not exist in your Datasource#2's corresponding column...

So for test purpose try following..

```
<asp:ListBox .. AppendDataBoundItems="true"> 
   <Items>       
 <asp:ListItem Text="NA" Value="" />   
 </Items>
 </asp:ListBox >
```

Comment: I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException saying SelectedValue has a value which is not in the element list, but all of my values should be inside of it.

Comment: I manually set all items of Val to one value existing in my datasource #2 but I still get the same error. Do I maybe need to cast the values of my datasource #2 which is a DataTable and therefore returning objects?

Comment: Try SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Val") %>' ..you need to have different quotes inside and outside ,so compiler can distinguish between two..

Comment: I did it old stylish using events provided by the datagrid.